# How to use pthread php in REST api call

Tags: php, multithreading, rest, pthreads

I'm developing a REST server in php, i have some service that call an external matlab script. I need to use multithreading to execute this heavy processes in background. Someone suggest me to use pthreads php extension and i try to create what i need without success.

For example : (Here's an example to clarify what I would like to)

```
GET www.rest.api.com/startThread/someID=X   
return {"message":"thread [someID=X] started"}

GET www.rest.api.com/startThread/someID=X   
return {"message":"thread [someID=X] already in execution"}

GET www.rest.api.com/startThread/anotherID=Y   
return {"message":"thread [anotherID=Y] started"}

--------> if the thread X finish his execution i can restart the thread
GET www.rest.api.com/startThread/someID=X   
return {"message":"thread [someID=X] started"}
```

Comment: ... and your question is?

Comment: I suggest you to read a little about the X/Y Problem while you're wondering: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 0):

You can try a callback queue pattern within RabbitMq. take a look for details [here](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-php.html)